# Make private scope of a variable inside a function to global and access it globally in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Though there were similar type of questions were already asked here..I tried all those but invain .So,I am creating new question.

I am passing a variable to function as argument and then assigning that variable to a global variable inside the function only not outside.Now,I have to access the global variable which was created inside the function globally outside the function.

```
function update_ui(latLng ) {
console.log(latLng,'From lat and lng');
  globalvar=latLng; or window.globalvar=latLng;
}
update_ui();//Calling the function 
console.log(globavar);// Undefined (But ,I need to the LntLng Valuese that I passed above)
```

Comment: You are logging `globavar` instead of `globalvar`.

Comment: Soory @EvanKnowles,That was typing mistake ,but on production code it was "globarvar".

Comment: Please update with the actual code.

Comment: That was the actual code block  or function ,I am using on my code even the variable names and function name is also same..@EvanKnowles....Do you want more?

Comment: Your code block has the word `or` in it?

Comment: As a part of normal text yes there was "or" word, but there was no word "or" in my hard JS code.@EvanKnowles

Answer (score 0):

As long as `globalvar` was not defined in the function, or in a function wrapping the `update_ui` function, the two statements:

- `globalvar = latLng`
- `window.globalvar = latLng`

are identical. As @Evan mentioned, in the comment, you have a typo there. In your comment you still have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the globalvar variable in global scope before using it in your function.

```
var globalvar = '';

function update_ui(latLng) {
    console.log(latLng, 'From lat and lng');
    globalvar = latLng;
}

update_ui('test-value'); //Calling the function 
console.log(globalvar);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..But this did not helped me @Michael Stork